# Trying to change the date format on iOS

Tags: ios, date, format

I parse a date from an xml file and store it in a string variable like this :

```
NSString *dateTex = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"];
```

When i try to print this variable on console i get :

the object value is:Fri, 01 Jun 2012 15:52:00 GMT

I am trying to change the format of the above date , to be stored again in a string variable but like this : dd/mm/yy.
I tried this code :

```
//changing dates format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTex];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSString *dateText = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter2 release];
NSLog(@"the object value is:%@",dateText);
```

But when i print the dateText variable on console i get :

the object value is:(null)

What am i doing wrong and the date is never stored in the variable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,(`setDateFormat` line is changed).

```
    //changing dates format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; // changed line in your code

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTex];
    [dateFormatter release];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // changed line in your code
    NSString *dateText = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter2 release];
    NSLog(@"the object value is:%@",dateText);
```

For Calender year use: 'yyyy' and for month use: 'MM'

Answer (score 0):

Probably you parsing format is wrong. Check, if NSDate* date is filled correctly.

Perhaps you need another d, because you get the day with a leading zero. 
Try: `EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format for the first dateformatter is wrong. It should be
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"];

Hope this helps.